# htmlConverter in itext7 closes the pdf document before I want it to be closed in C#

Tags: c#, itext7, html-to-pdf

I'm using iText7 to convert from HTML to PDF which runs perfectly

however this call:

```
   HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlStream, document);
```

will close the document after it's called but I don't want to close the document yet for the following reason

I wrote this function to write pages I'll be calling it in a loop

```
   public static void WritePage(string htmlbody)
    {
        document.AddNewPage();
        byte[] htmlByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlbody); 
        MemoryStream htmlStream = new MemoryStream(htmlByteArray);       
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlStream, document);
    }
```

and after the loop is over I'll close the document my self

```
 public static void CloseDocument()
    {   
       document.Close();
    }
```

this worked when I was using iText5 but now the convertToPdf will close the document.
I can read from that document and add it with the new page to a new document but I don't want to do that 
I want to utilize the built in document.AddNewPage and after the document is fully constructed I'll close it myself

Thank you in advance

Comment: I found the answer here https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-parse-multiple-html-files-one-pdf

Comment: Yep, it's in the tutorial. Could you please add a short answer to your question. I'd certainly up-vote such an answer because it's also helpful for other people with the same question.

Comment: thanks @BrunoLowagie I added the answer

Comment: OK, I've upvoted the answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer#1 is using PdfMerger and it is my preferred answer

```
public void createPdf(String baseUri, String[] src, String dest) throws IOException { 
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
for (String html : src) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(html), temp, properties);
    temp = new PdfDocument(
        new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())));
    merger.merge(temp, 1, temp.getNumberOfPages());
    temp.close();
}
pdf.close();}
```

answer#2 is converting the html to IElement List and adding that to the document like in follwoing code:

```
public void createPdf(String baseUri, String[] src, String dest) throws IOException { 
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
for (String html : src) {
    List<IElement> elements =
        HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(html), properties);
    for (IElement element : elements) {
        document.add((IBlockElement)element);
    }
}
document.close();}
```

Reference: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-parse-multiple-html-files-one-pdf